# Is there any way to check that texts escaped or not on a Chrome browser Developer tools?

Tags: html, security, escaping, google-chrome-devtools, html-escape-characters

I wondered if there is a way to check texts escaped or not.

"Edit as HTML" of "Element tab" appeared by a right-click does not seem to meet my request.

That means quotations are changed to non escaped characters despite the input value is escaping.

[image: chrome developer tool]

Do you know a better way?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Devtools inspector shows the live DOM/HTML so to see the original source go to the `Sources` panel.

Comment: Thank you, wOxxOm. I would like to see escaped code, not original code if possible. The original code is JavaScript like React or vanilla JavaScript. Is there any way?

I saw an official page that React DOM escapes any values embedded in JSX before rendering them and I thought so.
https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Comment: Try `$0.innerHTML` in devtools console after selecting an element.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, the result was the same as the image I posted...